# How can I make Windows explore a DVD instead of playing it by default?

Tags: windows, dvd, autoplay

How can I make Windows explore a DVD (which consists of a `video_ts` folder and `.ifo`, `.bup`, `.vob` files in it), just by clicking the DVD drive icon in My Computer?

Right now, when clicking this icon, it's playing the DVD with Windows Media Player. I however just want to explore its contents – without needing to right click and selecting *Explore*, and without safe mode.

Also, what actually makes DVD movies auto-play? Executable files on a disc are auto-playing through `autorun.inf`. But which file on the DVD is used to auto-run?

Comment: There's no autorun file on a video DVD. Windows just knows it's a video DVD (because of its contents) and will play it when inserted.

Comment: which version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score -1):

to view the contents you have to right click and select open.  dvd's can have an auto run for things like a built in dvd player app but usually windows automatically starts the chooser app or if you told windows it will start media player automatically.  cant remember if it is in defult apps or if there is another control pannel applet that sets what to do.

Right click on the dvd drive select properties then go to autoplay select dvd movie.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I missed the part of default action.  there is still a control applet that sets default actions.  If I go to windows tomorrow I will see about getting a screenshot of it.